# Compute eigenvalues of Hessian = $\begin{bmatrix}a&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ such that function is convex/eigenvalues $\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

The Hessian matrix is given to be $\begin{bmatrix}a&1\\1&2 \end{bmatrix}$ where $a$ is a real number.

EDIT: So to find the eigenvalues I find the determinant which is ad-bc so 2a-1.

So in order for the function to be convex $a\geq\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

However: you the determinant of the matrix is not $(\lambda - a)(\lambda -2)-1$.

The determinant of the matrix ${\bf M}$ is $2a-1$.

You found, quite rightly, the determinant $\det(\lambda\bf{I} - {\bf M})$.

Comment: I am going to get some sleep, I am making very silly mistakes now. Thank you for pointing it out !